# Docker volume directories owned by root (not using Dockerfile)

Tags: docker, payara

I'm deploying a java web application in a docker container through Payara Server (micro).

To ease the deployment, I'm not planning on using a custom Docker Image through a Dockerfile, but simply launching my application through a `docker run` command.

I'm currently using 3 different volumes:

- One for deploying my .war file into the autodeploy folder /opt/payara/deployments
- One for a configuration file (.properties) used by my Java application
- One for collecting logs

The problem is that the folders being created by the volumes are all owned by root, thus not accessible by Payara.

For example, the configuration.properties file goes into the /etc folder which doesn't exist by default in a payara/micro image, so it gets created automatically by the volume, but with root as the owner instead of Payara.

I'd like to know if there was a way to fix this problem without having to create a specific Dockerfile. I already have a custom image built where i use the RUN command in the Dockerfile to create these directories, but that's not what I'm trying to do here.

Here's the docker run command i'm currently using:

```
docker run -dp 8080:8080 --name app -e KEY1="1" -e KEY2="2" -v $(pwd)/app.war:/opt/payara/deployments/app.war -v $(pwd)/configuration.properties:/opt/payara/etc/my-app/configuration.properties -v $(pwd)/logs:/opt/payara/var/my-app/api/log payara/micro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide **-u** argument to run command to run container as a specific user, in this case **root**. However, running container as root is not recommended.

```
-u="", --user="": Sets the username or UID used and optionally the groupname or GID for the specified command.

The followings examples are all valid:
--user=[ user | user:group | uid | uid:gid | user:gid | uid:group ]
```

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) is docker docs link.

Comment: Running my container as root messes up its home folder, which is something I dont want to do